# Creating a new variable while looking back at previous rows

Tags: r, datetime, lag, dplyr

I have a simple dataset of patient visits:

```
date        infection
2005-01-01  yes
2005-06-30  yes
2005-10-15  yes
2006-01-01  no
2006-06-01  no
2006-11-01  yes
2006-12-01  no
2007-11-15  yes
```

In R, I want to add a column named `chronic` which takes the value `yes`, `no`, `NA`.

- It says the value `yes` only if infection=='yes' for the current date AND there are two infection=='yes' rows in the previous 365 days.
- Otherwise, it takes `NA` if there weren't two visits in the previous 365 days
- Otherwise, it takes `no`

So the final dataset would look like this:

```
date        infection chronic
2005-01-01  yes       NA
2005-06-30  yes       NA
2005-10-15  yes       yes
2006-01-01  no        no
2006-06-01  no        no
2006-11-01  yes       no
2006-12-01  no        no
2007-11-15  yes       NA
```

How would I code this? I'd ideally like to use `dplyr`, but I am open to any solutions. Thank you!

Dataset can be recreated with this code:

```r
dat <- data.frame(date = c(as.Date("2005-01-01"), as.Date("2005-06-30"), as.Date("2005-10-15"), as.Date("2006-01-01"), as.Date("2006-06-01"), as.Date("2006-11-01"), as.Date("2006-12-01"), as.Date("2007-11-15")), infection = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `map` functions from `purrr` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat %>%
  mutate(chronic = map2_chr(date, infection, 
         ~case_when(.y == 'yes' & 
                    sum(infection[between(date, .x-365, .x - 1)] == 'yes') >= 2 ~ 'yes', 
                    .y == 'yes' & 
                    sum(infection[between(date, .x-365, .x - 1)] == 'yes') != 2 ~ NA_character_, 
                    TRUE ~ 'no')))

#        date infection chronic
#1 2005-01-01       yes    <NA>
#2 2005-06-30       yes    <NA>
#3 2005-10-15       yes     yes
#4 2006-01-01        no      no
#5 2006-06-01        no      no
#6 2006-11-01       yes    <NA>
#7 2006-12-01        no      no
#8 2007-11-15       yes    <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using `data.table` and a range-based (non-equi) merge/join.

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr) # not required, just used to show the flow

dat <- fread(text = "
date        infection
2005-01-01  yes
2005-06-30  yes
2005-10-15  yes
2006-01-01  no
2006-06-01  no
2006-11-01  yes
2006-12-01  no
2007-11-15  yes")[, date := as.Date(date)]
```

Code:

```r
copy(dat) %>%
  .[, c("date0", "date1") := .(date - 365, date)] %>%
  dat[., on = .(date >= date0, date <= date1) ] %>%
  .[, .(infection = last(infection), n_visits = .N,
        n_infect = sum(infection == "yes")), by = .(i.date)] %>%
  setnames(., "i.date", "date") %>%
  .[, chronic := fcase(
    n_visits < 3, NA_character_,
    infection == "yes" & n_infect >= 2, "yes",
    rep(TRUE, .N), "no") ] %>%
  .[]
#          date infection n_visits n_infect chronic
#        <Date>    <char>    <int>    <int>  <char>
# 1: 2005-01-01       yes        1        1    <NA>
# 2: 2005-06-30       yes        2        2    <NA>
# 3: 2005-10-15       yes        3        3     yes
# 4: 2006-01-01        no        4        3      no
# 5: 2006-06-01        no        4        2      no
# 6: 2006-11-01       yes        3        1      no
# 7: 2006-12-01        no        4        1      no
# 8: 2007-11-15       yes        2        1    <NA>
```